# how to replace Inf and NaN with zero using built in function

Tags: matlab, octave

In octave, is there a build in function for replacing Inf/NaN to 0 in a vector

For example

```
a = log10([30 40 0 60]) => [1.4771 1.6021 -Inf 1.7782]
```

I can use finite or find function to find the index/position of the valid values
but I don't know how to copy the values correctly without writing a function.

```
finite(a) => [1 1 0 1]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
>> a = log10([30 40 0 60])
a =
      1.477    1.602    -Inf    1.778

>> a(~isfinite(a))=0
a =
      1.477    1.602    0       1.778
```

does the trick, this uses [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.nl/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html)

`~` is the NOT operator for boolean/logical values and `isfinite(a)` generates a logical vector, same size as a:

```
>> ~isfinite(a)
ans =
     0     0     1     0
```

As you can see, this is used for the logical indexing.

Answer (score 6):

Similarly for NaN, you can use `isnan()` to replace these elements with whatever you want.