# Replace Inf by a number in an anonymous function

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, anonymous-function

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485294/how-to-replace-inf-and-nan-with-zero-using-built-in-function) expalins how to get rid of Infs using the logic indexing. The problem is that I don't have an array; Infs are generated by an anonymous function. I have tried to get rid of them using embedded conditions, but it does not work properly replacing Inf by NaN. Below is my example:

```
fun = @(x) 1./x.*(x~=0)+10.*(x==0)
```

It is supposed to get 10 when x=0, but the output is NaN in this case, because `Inf.*0=NaN`. I will appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple fix would be to move the condition into the denominator:

```
fun = @(x) 1./( x.*(x~=0) + (x==0)/10 );
```

Comment: It is a good solution if the replacement and its inverse is known and simple, like 10 in this case. If I place some another function instead of 10 there might be problems. Anyway it is out of the question's scope

Answer (score 3):

I have just found another solution using complex numbers

```
a = 1e-10*1j;    % very small imaginary number
fun = @(x) real(1./(x+a).*(real(x+a)~=0)+10.*(real(x+a)==0));
```

Comment: Nice.  Since most of my work is in the Reals, I always forget to offer a Complex solution.