# MATLAB: Remove Inf or NaN

Tags: arrays, matlab, object, structure

If I have a **structure** that contains `-Inf`, `Inf`, or `NaN` entries I want to replace them with 0 or empty. Is this possible, and if so how would this be implemented? It needs to also work for nested data.

`Isinf()` and `isnan()` wont work on a structure array.

Example:

```
test(1).a = 1;
test(2).a = Inf;
test(1).b = NaN;
test(2).b = 2;
```

However the fieldnames could be anything, and should be assumed to be unknown. This structure prints out like this:

```
a b 1 1 NaN 2 Inf 2
```

And I would like it to be:

```
a b 1 1 0 2 0 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to replace Inf and NaN with zero using built in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485294/how-to-replace-inf-and-nan-with-zero-using-built-in-function)

Comment: i had a look at that alreay, but i cannot use the isinf or isnan functions on a structure array....

Comment: Are the structure fields scalars, or arrays that you want to remove `Inf` and `NaN` elements from? And could your fields contain substructures that need to be operated on as well?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your structure does not contain any sub-structures to recurse through, and that you only want to find *scalar* values of `Inf` and `NaN` and replace them with 0 or `[]`, here's how you can easily do this:

```
s = struct('a', {1, Inf}, 'b', {NaN, 2});  % Sample data

f = fieldnames(s);   % Get field names
c = struct2cell(s);  % Convert structure to a cell array
[c{cellfun(@(d) isnumeric(d) && isscalar(d) && ~isfinite(d), c)}] = deal(0);
s = cell2struct(c, f, 1);  % Rebuild structure array
```

And the output:

```
s(1)

ans = 
  struct with fields:
    a: 1
    b: 0

s(2)

ans = 
  struct with fields:
    a: 0
    b: 2
```

You can replace the `deal(0)` with `deal([])` if you would rather have empty fields than zeroes.

### How it works...

The functions [`fieldnames`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html) and [`struct2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html) are first used to convert the structure array to a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of field names `f` and a cell array of field contents `c`. This will be easier to work with.

Next, [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) is used to apply an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to each cell of `c`. This function checks first for [numeric values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnumeric.html), then checks those to see if they're [scalar matrices](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isscalar.html), and finally checks those to see if they are not [finite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfinite.html). This returns a [logical array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) (with `true` for cells where scalar `Inf` or `NaN` values are found) that is used to index into `c` and assign a value of 0 using [`deal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html).

Finally, the structure array is reconstituted using [`cell2struct`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html) with the original field names in `f` and the modified field contents in `c`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Use MATLAB's isnan and isinf functions as follows:

```
mat(isinf(mat) | isnan(mat)) = 0;
```

**Example**

```
%defines input matrix
mat = rand(3,3); mat(1,1) = nan;
mat(2,3) = inf;mat(2,2) = -inf;

%replaces nans and infs with zeros
mat(isinf(mat) | isnan(mat)) = 0;
```

**Result**

```
mat =

0    0.0357    0.6787
0.9595         0         0
0.6557    0.9340    0.7431
```

Comment: This is a problem I cam across previosuly; your method works fine for cell array, but for a structure array its not possible, as it throws the error: Undefined function 'isinf' for input arguments of type 'struct'.

Comment: Please provide a simple example of the format of your struct so we know how to access your values!

Comment: test(1).a = 1
test(2).a = Inf
test(1).b = NaN
test(2).b = 2

However the fieldnames could be anything, and should be assumed to be unknown. This structure prints out like this:

      a       b
1    1     NaN
2   Inf      2

And I would like it to be:

      a       b
1    1      0
2    0      2

Comment: sorry it stackoverfow has removed newlines so messed up formatting

Comment: @Seb edit you original question and add your example